# How to migrate a Firebird's Trigger to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers, migration, firebird

I'm migrating an entire database from Firebird to PostgreSQL and it's not rocket science. But I'm having serious trouble with triggers. Specially the Firebird's POSITION argument.

Actually, I'm searching about the POSITION behavior. I need it but in PostgreSQL.

Those are the Triggers in Firebird:

This Trigger needs to be executed first:

```
/* Trigger: TRG_CFE_ESTOQUE_PROCESSADO */
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TRG_CFE_ESTOQUE_PROCESSADO FOR ITENS_CFE
 BEFORE UPDATE POSITION 0
AS                                                                                                                  
BEGIN                                                                                                               
  IF(NEW.ITE_QTD <> OLD.ITE_QTD)THEN                                                                                
  BEGIN                                                                                                             
    NEW.ITE_ESTOQUE_PROCESSADO = 'N';                                                                             
  END                                                                                                               
END
```

And this one needs to be executed after:

```sql
/* Trigger: TRG_CFE_ESTOQUE_EXCLUIDO */
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TRG_CFE_ESTOQUE_EXCLUIDO FOR ITENS_CFE
 BEFORE DELETE POSITION 1
AS                                                                                                                  
BEGIN                                                                                                               
  UPDATE ITENS_CFE                                                                                                  
     SET ITE_ESTOQUE_PROCESSADO = 'N'                                                                             
   WHERE PRO_CODIGO             = OLD.PRO_CODIGO                                                                    
     AND CFE_CODIGO             = OLD.CFE_CODIGO;                                                                   
END
```

For now, I'm not testing it, just searching for a way to reproduce the expected behavior.

Comment: A `BEFORE UPDATE` and a `BEFORE DELETE` would never fire for the same event at all. Between these two, the position is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Searching again, I've found something in the [PostgreSQL Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createtrigger.html):

> If multiple triggers of the same kind are defined for the same event, they will be fired in alphabetical order by name

And I think it will do the magic.

But is this the **best way** of doing it?

Comment: These don't appear to be on the same event, though.

Comment: @Jeremy "triggers of the same kind " - not "on the same event" ?

Comment: Guess it is that very "UNIX WAY", like those `init.d` scripts names `S_00_MeaningfulNameHere` then `S_01_MeaningfulNameHere`, etc. Guess if you switch all your triggers on that naming convention - this approach can work well. But personally i'd think about making one umbrella trigger, and then calling several Stored Procedures from it in the order I need. Whether in is easy or hard in PG to convert particular tiggers into SP I don't know

Comment: That's an excellent idea, @arioch-the! And as I said on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992042/how-to-migrate-a-firebirds-trigger-to-postgresql/56992810?noredirect=1#comment100547007_56992810) for the answer above, I'm just being as loyal to the old scripts as I can. At least for now.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way I've defined trigger would be like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_table_x_after_insert()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_y
        (id)
    VALUES
        (NEW.id)
    ;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_table_x_after_insert
AFTER INSERT ON table_x
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_table_x_after_insert();
```

The function you define can handle multiple steps.

Comment: Thanks but, this doesn't answer the question about the position thing, right?

Comment: I guess not really but I don't see the need for the ordering of these triggers being that they're different operations (`DELETE` and `UPDATE`) and they both set `ITE_ESTOQUE_PROCESSADO = 'N'`. What I was really going for was the possibility that one trigger can perform both actions. Is the concern that upon the `DELETE` trigger being fired the `UPDATE` trigger wont execute first?

Comment: Right, I see what you were meaning. Actually I'm trying to make triggers that replicate the old database behavior and to do so, I'm just being as loyal to the old scripts as I can.
But there are several optimizations to be done.